# Swagger OpenAPI describing string array in multipart request

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I need to describe a multipart query that has an array of strings. But I ran into a problem, in the query, the array elements are combined into one string instead of being separate string items. I am using OpenApi 3.0.3

```
              "multipart/form-data": {
                "schema": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": ["image"],
                    "properties": {
                        "image": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "format": "base64",
                            "description": "Banner image `1920x90, 2mb`"
                        },
                        "name": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "example": "Docs banner",
                            "description": "Banner name"
                        },
                        "link": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "description": "Banner link"
                        },
                        "page[]": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "example": ["HOME", "LIVE", "CHANNELS"],
                            "enum":[
                                "HOME",
                                "LIVE",
                                "CHANNELS",
                                "ARTISTS",
                                "DISCOVER",
                                "MYLIST",
                                "PROGRAM",
                                "PLAYER"
                             ],
                             "description":"Banner pages"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

What I received: `page: [ 'HOME,LIVE,CHANNELS' ]`
What I expect: `page: [ 'HOME','LIVE','CHANNELS' ]`

Comment: The issue is likely with the server implementation. What server-side framework/library do you use? Can you post your controller code with annotations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very clear where exactly do you receive `page: [ 'HOME,LIVE,CHANNELS' ]`, but looks like in enum there are possible values for items of your array. Try this:

```json
"multipart/form-data": {
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "required": ["image"],
        "properties": {
            "image": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "base64",
                "description": "Banner image `1920x90, 2mb`"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "example": "Docs banner",
                "description": "Banner name"
            },
            "link": {
                "type": "string",
                "description": "Banner link"
            },
            "page[]": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum":[
                        "HOME",
                        "LIVE",
                        "CHANNELS",
                        "ARTISTS",
                        "DISCOVER",
                        "MYLIST",
                        "PROGRAM",
                        "PLAYER"
                     ],
                     "example": "HOME"
                },
                "example": [ "HOME", "LIVE", "CHANNELS" ],
                "description":"Banner pages"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can look for more details at the specification for [adding examples](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/adding-examples/).

This structure allows you to send multiple string enum items for `page` element, screenshot from [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/) is below:

[image]

Comment: I am getting this value in the request that swagger sends. The solution you suggested works, but it only allows you to select one element, while I need the ability to add multiple elements to the array

Comment: @Luzz: yyunikov's array definition is in fact correct (even though it probably isn't related to the issue in question). The `enum` must be alongside `type: items` rather than alongside `type: array`. To select multiple array items in Swagger UI, you can Ctrl+click and Shift-click the items in the rendered list box.

Comment: @Luzz can you show an example? what does swagger sends mean exactly? you can check the spec on https://editor.swagger.io/. the description of such API allows sending multiple items. I've attached the picture from Swagger editor.

Comment: @Luzz updated the answer, let me know if it's clear.