# Swagger OpenAPI describing string array in multipart requestt

Tags: node.js, swagger, openapi

I need to describe a multipart query that has an array of strings. But I ran into a problem, in the query, the array elements are combined into one string instead of being separate string items. I am using OpenApi 3.0.3)

```
requestBody: {
          content: {
            'multipart/form-data': {
              schema: {
                type: 'object',
                properties: {
                  email: {
                    type: 'string',
                  },
                  password: {
                    type: 'string',
                  },
                  confirmPassword: {
                    type: 'string',
                  },
                  fullName: {
                    type: 'string',
                  },
                  avatar: {
                    type: 'string',
                    format: 'binary',
                  },
                  'genreIds[]': {
                    type: 'array',
                    items: {
                      oneOf: {
                        type: 'string',
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  'languageIds[]': {
                    type: 'array',
                    items: {
                      type: 'string',
                      default: '',
                    },
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
```

What I received: `genreIds: [ '1234,55466,2455' ]` What I expect: `genreIds: [ '1234','55466','2455' ]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swagger OpenAPI describing string array in multipart request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72124546/swagger-openapi-describing-string-array-in-multipart-request)